# How can I write sum function as fast as c++ in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Following 2 versions `mysum` functions in haskell are 10 times slower than c++ version (with `ghc -O`). How can I optimize `mysum` function further?

```hs
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = print $ mysum [1..100000000] 0

mysum ::Num a =>[a]->a->a
mysum (x:xs) !s = mysum xs (x + s)
mysum [] !s = s
```

```hs
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = print $ mysum 0 100000000 0

mysum ::(Num a,Eq a) =>a->a->a->a
mysum !from !to !now | from == to = now + from
                     | otherwise = mysum (from+1) to (now+from)
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    unsigned long long a = 0;
    for(unsigned long long i =0;i<=100000000;++i){
        a+=i;
    }
    printf("%llu", a);
}
```

Comment: BTW if I compile that C++ program, I get a program that doesn't compute anything and simply prints a precomputed 5000000050000000.

Comment: I added `if (a==5050){ printf("aaa"); }` inside `for loop`. Output `aaa5000000050000000`. So `for loop` had run. And `c++` version speed even 10 times faster than haskell version.

Comment: try, to use monomorphic version. Instead of `Num a => ... `, just use an concrete type like `Int`.  Compile with `-O2`. Also, try writing using `foldl'` from Data.Foldable or  `sum`. which are built in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: below in the comments @leftaroundabout points out that using `ghc -O2` (and using `Int`s, I guess) is already enough, even without the manual optimizations I did in this answer.

---

Original Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, NumericUnderscores #-}
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = print $ mysum [1 .. 100_000_000] 0

mysum :: Num a => [a] -> a -> a
mysum (x:xs) !s = mysum xs (x + s)
mysum [] !s = s
```

Compiling it with `ghc -O2`, we get:

```
$ time ./Sum1
5000000050000000

real    0m1,913s
user    0m1,904s
sys 0m0,008s
```

New code, with minor changes from your attempt:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, NumericUnderscores #-}
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = print $ mysum 1 100_000_000 (0 :: Int)

{-# SPECIALIZE mysum :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int #-}
mysum ::(Num a,Eq a) =>a->a->a->a
mysum !from !to !now | from == to = now + from
                     | otherwise = mysum (from+1) to (now+from)
```

Compiling it with `ghc -O2`, we get:

```
$ time ./Sum2 
5000000050000000

real    0m0,122s
user    0m0,118s
sys 0m0,004s
```

This is a **15.6x speedup**. C++ is still faster since it removes the loop. If I add `if (a == ...) printf(...);` in the loop so to force the loop to run, C++ yields `real 0m0,108s` which is on-par with Haskell (but, IMO, the comparison is now unfair since C++ has an extra `if`).

Anyway, to make Haskell faster I did the following:

- Use `Int`, not the default `Integer` for numeric values.
- Specialize the `mysum` function to `Int`, telling GHC to produce optimized code for that special case, beyond the standard polymorphic code. Polymorphism makes `mysum` much slower.

Finally, always remember to use `ghc -O2` to turn optimizations on (and don't use GHCi to measure performance).

Comment: I actually get the same good performance even without bang patterns and `SPECIALIZE`, looks like `-O2` is smart enough to figure this out by itself (0,024±0.002 seconds on my machine both with and without).

Comment: ...which is in fact also almost exactly as fast as `g++ -O2` when I avoid precomputing the result but remove any extra conditions from the assembly.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Interesting, I missed that. Probably in my first experiments I forgot to  add `::Int`, and went to `SPECIALIZE` too soon.

Comment: `-fllvm` will likely do what C++ did: remove the loop, and replace it with a constant.